# Subtract 2 Datepickers

Tags: ios7, nsdate, xcode5, uidatepicker

I currently have 2 date pickers where the user can select start date and end date. I would like to know the difference between the 2 in minutes or hours. The values will be stored into 2 NSDate variables I'm assuming? So how is it I can subtract the 2 NSDates and get a float value. Thank you very much.

My answer

```
    NSTimeInterval timeInseconds1 = [[startTimePicker date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval timeInseconds2 = [[endTimePicker date] timeIntervalSince1970];
float difference = timeInseconds2 - timeInseconds1;
NSLog(@"%f", difference);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at:

```
[date timeIntervalSince1970]
```

will get you a NSTimeInterval which is defined as a double in seconds. You can do that math from there and then use

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:time]
```